# Lower bound of this harmonic series sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck on an excercise in my maths class. How can I find an explicit lower bound for the harmonic series sum:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{x}\,?$$

Comment: Why don't you ask on [mathematics.SE]?

Comment: $0$ is an obvious one. How good does this bound have to be? What do you know about the harmonic series? You should ask on [math.se] (not here, the question is off-topic) with a bit more information about what you already know and what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have asked this on [Math Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

But here's the soultion
$$\sum_{x=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+ \cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}$$
can be written as
$$\sum_{x=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{x}=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\right)+ \cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}$$
It can be observed that
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{7}{12}>\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{533}{840}>\frac{1}{2}$$
similarly
$$\frac{1}{2^m+1}+\frac{1}{2^m+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^m+2^m}>\frac{1}{2}$$
so, 
$$\sum_{x=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{x}\ge1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+ \cdots+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sum_{x=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{x}\ge1+\frac{k}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can get a very good bound by using an integral. Since $1/x$ is decreasing, we have
$$ \int_t^{t+1} \frac{dx}{x} \leq \int_t^{t+1} \frac{dx}{t} = \frac{1}{t}. $$
Therefore
$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \frac{1}{t} \geq \int_1^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} = \log (n+1). $$
Similarly,
$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \frac{1}{t} \leq 1 + \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x} = \log n + 1. $$
Even better estimates show that
$$ \sum_{t=1}^n \frac{1}{t} = \log n + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), $$
and the [Wikipedia article on Euler's constant $\gamma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) contains even more accurate expansions.